# Where col equal to value copy across to separate col - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know this has been asked a few times but I can't seem to get it working. I want to copy across row values to a separate column when equal to a specific value. Using the `df` below, when `np.nan` is located in `Member`, I want to copy across `np.nan` to `Group`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Member' : ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5',np.nan,np.nan],                 
    'Min' : [5,5,5,5,5,5,5],    
    'Max' : [10,10,10,10,10,10,10],                 
    'Group' : [26,26,26,26,26,26,26],                        
    })

# Attempt 1
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Member'] == np.nan, df['Group'], df['Member'])

# Attempt 2
df['Group']  = df.apply(lambda x: x['Member'] if x['Group'] == np.nan else x['Group'], axis=1)
```

Neither attempt works. The intended output is:

```
  Member  Min  Max  Group
0  C1     5    10   26   
1  C2     5    10   26   
2  C3     5    10   26   
3  C4     5    10   26   
4  C5     5    10   26   
5  NaN    5    10   Nan
6  NaN    5    10   Nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by your code with special function for test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and swapped `Member` with `Group` columns in `np.where`:

```
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Member'].isna(), df['Member'], df['Group'])

#alternative with notna
#df['Group'] = np.where(df['Member'].notna(), df['Group'], df['Member'])

#alternative with loc
#df.loc[df['Member'].isna(), 'Group'] = df['Member']
print (df)
  Member  Min  Max Group
0     C1    5   10    26
1     C2    5   10    26
2     C3    5   10    26
3     C4    5   10    26
4     C5    5   10    26
5    NaN    5   10   NaN
6    NaN    5   10   NaN
```